# What's the difference between [attribute|=value] and [attribute^=value] CSS selectors?

Tags: css, css-selectors

What is the difference between the following two CSS selectors?

`[attribute|=value]` and `[attribute^=value]`

On [W3Schools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W3Schools), the documentation says:

> [lang|=en]    Selects all elements with a lang attribute value starting with "en"
>
> a[href^="https"]    Selects every `<a>` element whose href attribute value begins with "https"

Is there a difference between "starting with" and "begins with" or will the two selectors match the same elements?

Comment: Consider searching other sites besides w3schools, like MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors they have much better information.

Comment: the two selectors are different (as they refer to different attributes) - but all other things being the same, see @MikeMcCaughan 's link...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[MDN has the better description](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors):

> `[attr|=value]`
>   Represents an element with an attribute name of
>   attr. Its value can be exactly “value” or can begin with “value”
>   immediately followed by “-” (U+002D). It can be used for language
>   subcode matches.
>
> `[attr^=value]`
>   Represents an element with an attribute name of attr
>   and whose value is prefixed by "value".

So `[attr|=foo]` would match `attr="foo"` or `attr="foo-bar"`, but not `attr="foobar"`.
`[attr^=foo]` on the other hand would match any of those.

The primary purpose of `|=` is, as described, for matching locale/language codes like `en-us`. Note that for languages specifically you should be using [`:lang()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:lang) however, which is a lot more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

They are similar, but slightly different. As the [W3 states](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#attribute-selectors) the pipe format: `[attribute|=value]`

> [att|=val] Represents an element with the att attribute, its value
>   either being exactly "val" or beginning with "val" immediately
>   followed by "-" (U+002D). This is primarily intended to allow language
>   subcode matches (e.g., the hreflang attribute on the a element in
>   HTML) as described in BCP 47 ([BCP47]) or its successor. For lang (or
>   xml:lang) language subcode matching, please see the :lang
>   pseudo-class.

So that matches an element with an attribute where the value is exactly `val` or the value begins with `val-`.

`[attribute^=value]` matches an element where the given attribute simply begins with `value`. This would match `<a href="https://www.google.com">` and `<a href="https://www.yahoo.com">`